# @azure/msal-node: Is there a way to log out / invalidate tokens?

Tags: node.js, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm using the `@azure/msal-node` package in a node application to enable my users to log in using their AzureAD credentials. Logging in and acquiring session tokens works fine, but  I cannot find a way to invalidate a session / log out a user - am I overlooking something obvious here?

Just for context, here's how I'm getting my tokens:

```
// msalConfig is my valid config object
const msalApp = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig); 

const authCodeUrlParameters = {
  scopes: ['user.read'],
  redirectUri: BASE_URL + '/msal-redirect'
};

try {
  const authCodeResponse = await msalApp.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters);
  reply.redirect(authCodeResponse);
} catch (e) {
  logError('auth code redirect error', e);
}
```

In the redirect handler, I'm doing this:

```
const tokenResponse = await msalApp.acquireTokenByCode({
  code: request.query.code,
  scopes: ['user.read'],
  redirectUri: BASE_URL + '/msal-redirect'
});
```

and then I'm using that token to display the logged in user etc.

What I'm missing is something like `msalApp.logout()` - what am I not seeing here?

Comment: did you solve in some way?

Comment: @Gianmarco I ended up forwarding my logout requests to here: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout

This is the brute force approach which signs out the user from Azure AD completely. I believe there is a logout URL to sign users out from just your specific app, but I can't seem to find it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately MSAL does not currently contain an `msalApp.logout()` API. Instead, you will have to manually implement the steps.

A logout operation will contain multiple steps:

- Removing the account and the tokens from the msal application cache.
- Redirecting to the AAD logout endpoint so the user logs out and AAD cookies are deleted.
- If your webapp has a session, invalidating it.

For removing the account and tokens from the msal application cache, you can do something along the lines of:

```
const accounts = msalApp.getTokenCache().getAllAccounts();
// filter on the account that you want to delete from the cache.
// I take the first one here to keep the code sample short
const account = accounts[0];
msalApp.getTokenCache().removeAccount(account);
```

For logging out from AAD, you'll have to redirect the user to the Azure AD logout endpoint. The [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request) should explain how to craft this request.

Comment: Thanks! I had found the logout endpoint in the meantime, but missed the part about removing the account from the app's token cache. Kind of a headscratcher though - it seems like this functionality would be easy enough to implement on the MSAL library's side, and logging out is an essential part of the user session lifecycle.

Comment: I tried in this way but seems that removeAccount doesn't work, I can still do silentLogin even if I logout

Comment: @Gianmarco please open up an issue in https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js with steps to reproduce.

Comment: Does not work: ```(node:20920) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1).```

Answer (score 2):

In answer of **sgonzalez**, I can see the error in "accounts". This const is a Promisse:

```
const accounts = msalApp.getTokenCache().getAllAccounts(); // <- is a Promisse
// filter on the account that you want to delete from the cache.
// I take the first one here to keep the code sample short
const account = accounts[0];
msalApp.getTokenCache().removeAccount(account);
```

Correcting:

```
pca.getTokenCache().getAllAccounts().then((response) => {
    const account = response[0];
    pca.getTokenCache().removeAccount(account).then(() => {
         res.sendStatus(200);
    }).catch((error) => {
         res.status(500).send({error});
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    res.status(500).send(error);
});
```

I don't know if this is the best way to implement it, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

MSAL doesn't expose accounts. You can try the following:

```
logout(options = {}) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    const accessToken = req.session?.accessToken
    if (accessToken) {
      let logoutUri = `${this.msalConfig.auth.authority}/oauth2/v2.0/`;

      if (options.postLogoutRedirectUri) {
        logoutUri += `logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=${options.postLogoutRedirectUri}`;
      }
      res.redirect(logoutUri);
    } else {
      return res.redirect("/login");
    }
  }
}
```

This worked for me. This will take you to the sign-out of the Microsoft page and you can choose the account you wish to logout from.