# MSAL - Logging Out via Python Desktop App

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to log out my MSAL desktop app.

I tried to adapt [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64235749) from JS to Python, and came up with:

```py
account = app.get_accounts()[0]
app.remove_account(account)
```

Then following [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request), I opened in the system browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout
```

And received confirmation that an account was logged out.

But after both steps, Graph API queries are still succeeding.

I also found [this AzureAD GitHub issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/94#issuecomment-534298337) which seemed to verify that the above should work, but IIUC they are relying on clearing web app session data as a guard. What I'm concerned about (and maybe I'm being paranoid) is that my access token continues to work even after logging out.